# Removing a OEM-installed kernel

Tags: 20.04, kernel

I have following kernels available in the system:

```
config-5.10.0-1057-oem        
config-5.11.0-46-generic      
config-5.13.0-25-generic      
config-5.13.0-27-generic
```

How do I remove `kernel 5.10.0-1057-oem` from the system, and therefore stop  the OEM kernel from updating? Currently, my system updates both generic and OEM kernels.

Answer (score 5):

Based upon your description, try:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.10.0-1057-oem
```

Comment: Yes, the answer solved the problem.